# Como agregar un option a un select con jquery en la primera posicion

Tags: jquery, html5

Tengo un select el cual lo lleno al darle  en un boton, con Jquery `$('#lider_id').append("<option value='1' >Josh_reder</option>")`
Pero el problema es que `.append` siempre los pone al final de los otros option, es decir el nuevo que se ingresa queda en la ultima posición de las opciones, lo que yo necesito es que al agregar un nuevo option lo ponga en la primera posición, de las opciones, no en la ultima

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De acuerdo con la [documentación oficial](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/), puedes utilizar `.prepend()`:

```
$('#lider_id').prepend("<option value='1' >Josh_reder</option>");
```

También, te recomendaría utilices la siguiente sintáxis:

```
let $option = $('<option />', {
    text: 'Josh_reder',
    value: 1,
});
$('#lider_id').prepend($option);
```

Código demostrativo:

```js
$('#prepend').on('click', function () {
  let $lider_list = $('#lider_id option');

  $('#lider_id').prepend($('<option />', {
    text: 'I: Líder ' + ($lider_list.length + 1),
    value: $lider_list.length + 1,
  }));
});

$('#append').on('click', function () {
  let $lider_list = $('#lider_id option');

  $('#lider_id').append($('<option />', {
    text: 'F: Líder ' + ($lider_list.length + 1),
    value: $lider_list.length + 1,
  }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="lider_id">
  <option value="1">Líder 1</option>
</select>

<button id="prepend">Añadir al inicio</button>
<button id="append">Añadir al final</button>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la repuesta, me ayudo mucho y también por el ejemplo

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza la función `.prepend` en vez de `.append`:

```js
$("#theSelectId").prepend("<option value='Auto 0' selected='selected'>Auto 0</option>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="theSelectId">
  <option value="Auto 1">Auto 1</option>
  <option value="Auto 2">Auto 2</option>
  <option value="Auto 3">Auto 3</option>
  <option value="Auto 4">Auto 4</option>
</select>
```

El método `.prepend ()` inserta el contenido especificado por el parámetro, al principio de cada elemento en el conjunto de elementos coincidentes (en este caso tu `select`).

Puedes revisar la documentación en la siguiente ruta: http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

Espero te ayude. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda amigo

Comment: Por nada, suerte compañero (Y).